# Emscripten installation error

Tags: ubuntu, emscripten

When trying to install Emscripten on Ubuntu i get an error
at this step:

```
./emsdk install latest.
```

[ 90%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/clang
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated. tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/build.make:220: the recipe is a mistake for the purpose of «bin/clang-3.9» make[2]: *** [bin/clang-3.9] Error 1 make[2]:**  Deleted file «bin/clang-3.9» CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10411: the recipe is a mistake for the purpose of «tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/all» make[1]:  **[tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: the recipe is a mistake for the purpose of «all»
make: *** [all] Error 2
Build failed due to exception!
Working directory: /home/pc/Документы/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.36.5/build_tag-e1.36.5_32
Command '['make', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Installation failed!

What must i do?

I added Ram and i got this error

[ 90%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/clang
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Memory exhausted
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/build.make:220: recipe for target 'bin/clang-3.9' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/clang-3.9] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10411: recipe for target 'tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Build failed due to exception!
Working directory: /home/pc/Desktop/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.36.5/build_tag-e1.36.5_32
Command '['make', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Installation failed!

Comment: which language is that ?

Comment: here's a better place for it then. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I wouldn't wait for you to ask !

Comment: If you can provide even an approximate translation of the error messages, you stand at least a chance of getting a reply here.